# get function declaration (present in pydoc output) with __doc__ attribute

Tags: python, pydoc

Example:

```
import numpy
print numpy.polydiv.__doc__
```

output:

> Returns the quotient and remainder of polynomial division...

While using pydoc:

```
$ pydoc numpy.polydiv
```

I get:

> numpy.polydiv = polydiv(u, v)
>       Returns the quotient and remainder of polynomial division...

Is there some available attribute that would allow me to get function declaration part `polydiv(u, v)` by using python script (without using pydoc/terminal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case you weren't aware, you can always use the [`help`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help) function in an interactive session to do the equivalent of what `pydoc` does.

But to answer your specific question:

The signature of a function object can be obtained using the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#module-inspect) module:

```
>>> import numpy, inspect
>>> def sig(func):
...     argspec = inspect.getargspec(func)
...     return func.__name__ + inspect.formatargspec(*argspec)
... 
>>> print sig(numpy.polydiv)
polydiv(u, v)
```

Comment: I just need it for part of script, no interactive mode. Was expecting some builtin attribute, but your answers does what I need. Thanks